# How would I normalize the following ANTLR grammar rules to eliminate left recursion?

Tags: grammar, ebnf

I'd like to be able to treat:

```
int(int, int)
```

As a function type. How do I normalize this (stripped down) grammar?

```
type : classOrInterfaceType | primitiveType | functionType;
functionType : type '(' (type (',' type)*)? ')';

classOrInterfaceType : ;
primitiveType : ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an algorithm for eliminating left recursion. http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~kal/PLT/PLT4.1.2.html